# Dependent Drop down functionality ng2-smart-table

Tags: angular6, ng2-smart-table

we have used ng2-smart-table for our project and I have a request now where one of the select input list is dependent upon selection of another list.
For instance, in the below example there are 2 Inputs (Country & Cities) and when User selects one of the Countries from drop down then the cities would get populated. So, whenever the user selects a different country then the Cities list would get populated with appropriates cities:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/28xKn.jpg)

Could someone please let me know if this is possible in ng2-smart-table?

My current settings

`mode: internal, 
   country: { 
      title: 'Country',
       type: 'html', 
       valuePrepareFunction: (cell, row) => { return cell },
       editor: {
         type: 'list', 
         config: 
            { list: [] 
            }, 
          }
        },
   city: { 
      title: 'City',
      type: 'html', 
      editor: 
       {
        type: 'list', 
        config: 
           { selectText: 'Select the Location to see options...', 
        list: [] 
         }, 
       } 
      }`

This is how the list is getting populated:

`let countryAll = this.countryService.getAll();
 let cityAll =this.cityService.getAll();`

`const countryOptions = [];
      for (const l of this.countryAll) {
        locationOptions.push({ value: l.name, title: l.name });
    }`

`this.settings.columns.country.editor.config.list = countryOptions;`

`const cityOptions = [];
      for (const l of this.cityAll) {
        locationOptions.push({ value: l.name, title: l.name });
    }`

`this.settings.columns.city.editor.config.list = cityOptions;`

Comment: when you clicked on Country you need to call API and fetch cities list... Am I right ?

Comment: Yes, Sachin. I need to be able to have updated Cities list whenever the user changes the Country

Comment: ok then I can help you. Just let know are you able to fetch changeEvent ?

Comment: No, I am not sure how to use change event upon selecting drop-down. If this is can be done then it will resolve my issue

Comment: So what is your issue ? Either issue in getting click event Or issue to bind updated value in dropdown ?

Comment: I have post my answer please update your status. So I can give you further help.

Comment: can you please clear your issue ? Either issue in fetch change event or issue in set updated data in cities dropdown ?

Answer (score 0):

To fetch click event try this way.

```
paymentStatus: {
    title: 'Country',
    type: 'html',
    valuePrepareFunction: (cell, row) => { return row },
    editor: {
      type: 'list',
      config: {
        list: [{ value: 1, title: 'India' }, { value: 2, title: 'Canada' }]
      }
    }
  },
```

Using **valuePrepareFunction()** you will be able to get data.

Then you have to call API and bind into dropdown.

Comment: @Deepak Welcome :)

Comment: mode: internal,
 country: {
          title: 'Country',
          type: 'html',          
          valuePrepareFunction: (cell, row) => { return cell },
          editor: {
            type: 'list',
            config: {
              list: []
            },
          }
        },
        city: {
          title: 'City',
          type: 'html',
          editor: {
            type: 'list',
            config: {
              selectText: 'Select the Location to see options...',
              list: []
            },
          }
        }

Comment: Hi Sachin, thanks for following up. I was out of town and couldnt follow up. As i have provided my settings above. 'mode: internal' setting is used. Can you let me know how to bind the return value from Country to pass on to Cities? Amd again thanks a lot for your help. Really appreciate!

Comment: @Deepak Can you please add above code in your question. So I can easily read it.

Comment: @Deepak I have also ask one question in comment under your question. Please reply of the question. So I'll be more clear on issue ... :)

Comment: Hi Sachin, I have added the code under question as you specified

Comment: @Deepak Can you please update your status ? Still issue is open ?

Answer (score 0):

> Below solution work for me:

[image]

```html
public settings = {
    actions: {
      position: 'right'
    },
    columns: {
      ctg_name: {
        title: 'Category',
      },
      ctg_visible: {
        title: 'Visible',
        editor: {
          type: 'list',
          config: {
            selectText: 'Select',
            list: [
              {value: '1', title:'True'},
              {value: '0', title:'False'}
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  };
```